# Paginate Observable in HTML with Mat-paginator and Mat-option

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, observable

I'm using angular material and observables to create an async list with `mat-paginator` and `mat-option` (instead of using a table, client requirements). I want to paginate this list in HTML but with the observable stream, not using a subscribe and an assignment to an auxiliary array paginated.

Example:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let elem of opMvAsync | async">
    <!-- Data printed here -->
</mat-option>
<mat-paginator *ngIf="(opMvAsync | async)?.length > 5" [length]="(opMvAsync | async)?.length" [hidePageSize]="true" [pageSize]="5" (page)="onPageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

And the TS:

```
//TS 
  opMvAsync : Observable<Array<Items>>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.opMvAsync = this.service.getItems();
}
```

I have another example in my app, very similar, but using an auxiliary array :

```
<!-- HTML-->
<mat-option *ngFor="let elem of lstPaginated">
    <!-- Data printed here -->
</mat-option>
<mat-paginator *ngIf="lstOri.length > 5" [length]="lstOri.length" [hidePageSize]="true" [pageSize]="5" (page)="onPageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>

// TS
lstOri: Array<Items>;
lstPaginated: Array<Items>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getItems().subscribe(r=> {
      this.lstOri= r;
      this.lstPaginated= this.lstOri.slice(0, 5);
  });
}
onPageChange(event: PageEvent) {
    this.lstPaginated= this.lstOri.slice(event.pageIndex * event.pageSize, event.pageIndex * event.pageSize + event.pageSize);
    }
```

This works fine, but it is quite laborious to have to handle two arrays constantly.

Is there any way to work directly paging the observable? Thanks for your advance.

**Edit:**  What I need is to figure it out the way in which I can paginate the observable that I'm rendering in HTML. My  `OnPageChange` should handle which elements of the observable I display, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by following below pattern.

1. In your `service`, instead of having a method `getItems()`, create a variable `items$`. And set its value to the get/post method call.
2. In your component, set `opMvAsync` equal to `service.items$`.
3. Now in your template, use it with `async` pipe.

**Below is the sample code:**

**my.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root', })
export class MyService {
  ...
  items$ = this.http.get('some/url/').pipe(...);
  ...
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
 ...
 public opMvAsync$ = this.service.items$.pipe(...);
 ...
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="opMvAsync$ | async as opMvAsync">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let elem of opMvAsync | async">
  <!-- Data printed here -->
  </mat-option>
</div>
```

This way you can avoid the subscribe/unsubcribe work, as `async` keyword will take care of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this does not solve my problem. What I need is figure it out the way in which I  can paginate the observable that I'm rendering in HTML.  My `` OnPageChange``` should handle which elements of the observable I display